# Save JS data in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My current code is:

```
Play.save = function() {

    //Hide the buttons
    this.printButton.visible = false;
    this.saveButton.visible = false;
    this.backButton.visible = false;

    //Force the game to re-render.
    this.game.cameras.render(); //generally not recommended if you can help it

    //Get the canvas information
    var img = this.game.stage.canvas.toDataURL("image/octet-stream");

    this.saveajax(img);

    //Show UI again.
    this.printButton.visible = false;
    this.saveButton.visible = true;
    this.backButton.visible = true;

}

Play.saveajax = function(img){
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "http://localhost/ourthing/character/save.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            img: img
        }
    });
}
```

The file 'save.php' works (when i simply open the file). It will execute a query which it has to do. Problem here is: with this script i want to update a user with the given post data (img). But it doesnt execute on this request.

**(i create data for var img and send this data to the saveajax function, which will open save.php to execute the query).**

Im very new to JS/ajax. Does anyone can help me?

Best regards

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console(F12 -> Console tab) ?

Comment: Yes,Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at State.Play.saveajax (dressup-1.0.0.js:502)
    at State.Play.save (dressup-1.0.0.js:474)
    at State.Play.checkInputs (dressup-1.0.0.js:495)
    at SignalBinding.execute (kiwi.js:5397)
    at Signal.dispatch (kiwi.js:5289)
    at InputManager._onUpEvent (kiwi.js:18273)
    at SignalBinding.execute (kiwi.js:5397)
    at Signal.dispatch (kiwi.js:5289)
    at Mouse.onMouseUp (kiwi.js:18713)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (kiwi.js:18636). It redirects to the saveajax function which i created.

Comment: That normally points as to not importing jQuery, are you importing it?

Comment: That is simple, your jquery library is not being included. Check the *Network*  tab for JS references. And double check the lib's url.

Comment: Oh I feel so terrible now. MANY MANY MANY Thanks! It works now. What a noobish failure. Im really happy for your both answers so fast! have a good day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

I had to include jQuery:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js" ></script >
```

Thanks @Don'tVoteMeDown and @Lixus

Save.php file:

```
$db = framework::getDBO();

    $data = array(
        'canvas_character' => $_POST['img'],
    );

    $db->where('id', 1);
    $db->update('ot_users', $data);
```

(i use my own framework)

Answer (score 0):

apparently I cant comment, so my question is what are you getting on save.php
with command like

```
error_log(print_r($_REQUEST,true));
```

I suspect JSON issue here. can we see save.php? 
Ok didn't see your previous comment, scrap that - your Jquery is not included.

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your reply. It has been fixed. I had to include jQuery.